# Best way to fetch data from database-style table with given row/column/table number - Java

Tags: java, database, switch-statement

I have several hypothetical 2 - dimensional tables, from which I am to fetch data. I need to make a method that will take in the table id and the "coordinates" of the desired item, and return the item. So far, I have tried making it with multi-layered `switch`es, but I am wondering whether there is any better way to go about this, as the switch code seems too long to be the optimal solution. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

An idea of what my code looks like:

```
switch(tableId) {
    case "table 1":
        switch(top) {
            case "whatever":
                switch(side) {
                    // et cetera
    case "table 2":
        // etc
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **[polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_in_object-oriented_programming)**.

Create an interface `SearchableTable`:

```
public interface SearchableTable<T> {
    T getItem(int x, int y);
}
```

If these tables are under your control, let them implement this interface. Otherwise, wrap the tables with your own wrapper-classes like so:

```
public class SearchableTableWrapper implements SearchableTable<MyItemType> {

    private final Table wrappedThirdPartyTable;

    public SearchableTableWrapper(Table wrappedThirdPartyTable) {
        this.wrappedThirdPartyTable = wrappedThirdPartyTable;
    }

    public MyItemType getItem(int x, int y) {
         ...
    }
}
```

Now, in the general class where you want to implement a general method that accepts a table id and indices of the item, accept the table itself and invoke its `getItem` method, like so:

```
public class TableUtils {
    public static <T> T getItem(SearchableTable<T> table, int x, int y) {
        return table.getItem(x, y);
    }
}
```

If you have to get table id instead of table, just keep a `Map` from table id to the relevant `SearchableTable`, like so:

```
public class TableUtils {

    private static Map<Long, SearchableTable> tableIdToSearchableTable;

    public static <T> T getItem(SearchableTable<T> table, int x, int y) {
        return table.getItem(x, y);
    }
}
```

This map can be loaded with the actual `SearchableTable`s in several ways, either via `static` initializer block or static `addTable` method or you could turn `TableUtils` to be non-static at all, whatever fits you best.

The main thing here is to use **polymorphism**.

**EDIT**

You don't need an `enum`. Your `Table1` from your comment should look like this:

```
public class Table1 implements SearchableTable<String> {
    public String getItem(int x, int y) {
        // use x and y to fetch the item friom the 2-dimensional data structure
    }
}
```

Comment: it lets you invoke `getItem` without switching between different tables. It's like saying "I don't care which exact table this is, I just want to make sure it has a `getItem` method and to invoke it" (sorry if the explanation is dummy :) )

Comment: Ok, so I made the interface, but when I try to implement it into a table, it tells me it wants an <identifier>. I wrote `public enum Table1 implements SearchableTable<String>`, and it still wants an <identifier>. Help please!

Comment: Well, see edit to my answer how your `Table1` should look like. I don't know what do you mean when you say `<identifier>`. Note that `SearchableTable<T>`'s parameterized type is `T` (a letter) and not a word... So where's the `identifier` coming from?

Comment: Oh, I see why - I tried to make my table an `enum`, and you have a class. I have switched to a class now.

Answer (score 1):

You have to rewrite everything in a more object oriented way, one smart way to do it in Java cold be the use of some 'tuned' enums :

```
enum activity { WHATEVER, SOMETHINGELSE } //Use the same principle as in the enum below ...

enum tables {
  TABLE1(activity.WHATEVER),
  TABLE2(activity.SOMETHINGELSE),

  private activity activity;

  tables(activity activity) {
    this.activity = activity;
  }

  public activity activity() {
   return this.activity;
  }
 }
```

After creating all the needed enum for each needed level, you can use the following "trick" to avoid the long and multilevel switch conditional statement :

```
String tableId = ...
//Load the table 
tables table = tables.valueOf(tableId);
//Call the related attached activity ...
table.activity();
```

Of course the enum element ***must have the same name*** as the variable name that you want to intercept(the same name that you would have put into the check condition of the if or switch statement).
Another similar result can be achieved using a map instead of an enum ...
Take a look at the [Command Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern), for further information .

Comment: Just wondering, how could I do this in other languages without enums, e.g. JavaScript?

Comment: You can achieve a similar result using a map or dictionary, or you can create a class similar to the java enum(remember that the Java enum is not a real enum, but is a "special" class).